# Single model reading and writing to several tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When registering to my website, users have to specify which company or group they are working for and then all the users are placed in one db table called users. I was wondering if it's possible to create a new table for every single company that registers and then put all users from that company to that one specific table while still having a single user model and a single controller.

Comment: Yes, possible, but what would that accomplish except greatly complicating your code/operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need multi-tenant application.

Here Each company/group can act as a tenant - all users are members of the tenant.

A simple library for this purpose is [Milia](https://github.com/jekuno/milia)

Please check the documentation and use accordingly.

It will save all companies users to the same table - But while retrieving apply the scope to find users of a particular tenant.

Comment: Ah yes, it _is_ possible that they want a multi-tenant app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a table for each company. You need to create tables called Companies and Users that are in relation with each other. So User belongs_to company. Then when you are creating a user you pass company_id to that user. You can read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html